# Language detection method "Browser" doesn't work if I check "Cache pages for anonymous users"

Tags: caching, i18n-l10n

I have two method detection activated in this order:

1- URL

2- Browser

Problem is that the method "Browser" doesn't work at all if "Cache pages for anonymous users" at 'admin/config/development/performance' is checked. **The default language is loaded all the time regardless the Browser language.**

It works fine if I uncheck "Cache pages for anonymous users".

See the captures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me know if I can provide any other information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you seen and tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792062/drupal-7-always-redirecting-to-default-language

> You might be affected by a bug in Drupal core. I had the same problem
>   for a while and finally found the cause and a workaround for it.
>
> It goes like this:
>
> 1. Add this code to a custom module (change "mymodule" to your modules' name):
>
>    ```
>    /**
>     * Implements hook_language_negotiation_info_alter().
>     *
>     * Remove the 'cache' setting from LOCALE_LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_BROWSER since
>     * the code that utilizes this setting will in fact prevent browser negotiation.
>     */
>    function mymodule_language_negotiation_info_alter(&$negotiation_info) {
>        unset($negotiation_info[LOCALE_LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_BROWSER]['cache']);
>    }
>    ```
> 2. Clear all caches (e.g. "drush cc all")
> 3. Go to admin/config/regional/language/configure and press "Save settings" once (this will rebuild the variable
>      'language_negotiation_language').
>
> Now browser language detection should work properly.
>
> I'm also looking for a real solution but this requires changes in core
>   and probably some discussion beforehand because of the nature of the
>   bug. I've opened an issue here: [Browser language detection for
>   anonymous requests is broken](https://drupal.org/node/2257843)

**there is [now a patch from Berdir](https://www.drupal.org/node/2257843#comment-9958085)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom module to unset the local languages, then it will be sort out your issue